# Prevent screen reader from reading title attribute

Tags: html, input, accessibility, screen-readers

We have an `input` slider that has a `title` attribute set to slider value. Since it doesn't have a label, we add `aria-label` to the input attribute. The thing is, screen reader will read out the slider value twice, I'm guessing the default input slider value, as well as the title since it's set to display the slider value.

Is there a way to prevent screen reader to NOT read out title attribute? We are mainly using it for tool-tip display.

Comment: Which screen reader are you using? Have you tried multiple screen readers? Same or different results?